# Extracting list of locations from text using R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a string containing many words [not sentences], I want to know how I can extract all the words that correspond to a location in that string for example:

```
text<-c("China","Japan","perspective","United Kingdom","formatting","clear","India","Sudan","United States of America","Bagel","Mongolian",...)
```

The output should be:

```
 > China, Japan, United Kingdom, Mongolian
```

something of the type. Basically I am looking at extracting locative information from random text.
This is a very general problem I am looking for guidance on how to model my solution, is there any dataset or something I can use to compare or extract information from. I dont want to carry out word by word comparison with
I am new to machine learning and R-programming, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If all your locations are countries, there are many lists of countries and you could create a large regex pattern of them, then str_extract_all the countries in your text.  Likewise, but harder for cities.

Comment: To do this generically, you should look into the [`openNLP`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/openNLP/index.html) package. It has a "named entity recognition" component that can use one of the [location models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) to do what you need.

Comment: it's models are not supported on R 3.2.2 @hrbrmstr I am trying to figure out how to use the "en-ner-location.bin" model. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this - how well it works really depends on how clean your input variable is but it works for your example data:

```
library(countrycode)
text[!is.na(countrycode(text, "country.name", "continent"))]

[1] "China"                    "Japan"                    "United Kingdom"          
[4] "India"                    "Sudan"                    "United States of America"
[7] "Mongolian"
```

Comment: it works rather fine but it I am not able to extract provinces, cities, etc. Any suggestions for that? Thanks a lot though.